# IBM-Cloud Public IP for Virtual Machine and corresponding public DNS

Tags: ibm-cloud

hi guys I have virtual machine in IBM Cloud this an IaaS environment, I've worked with Azure and I know AWS also gives an public DNS name to connect to your server instead of public IP I mean you can use both but the thing is I don't find where IBM Cloud does this, any one knows? I have public IP but no idea where is the public DNS
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ibm Cloud supports just answered since we were not able to find it in the portal

so public FQDN that Azure provides as optional and AWS gives you by default is not availble in 2019 for IBM Cloud :|